# Terminate subgraphs in Dask at runtime

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, dask, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have custom `Dask`'s graphs for processing large amounts of pictures.
Some of those pictures appear to be unusable at runtime, after a number of operations.

Right now, I propagate **None** to abort the subgraph, as for example :

```
# coding: utf-8
from dask import delayed

@delayed
def load(filename):
    print("Load " +filename)
    return filename

@delayed
def clean(data):
    if data == 'c.data':
        return None  # <========== Aborting
    print("clean " + data)
    return data

@delayed
def analyze(sequence):
    for s in sequence:
        if not s:
            continue
        print("Analyzing " + s)

inputs = ['a.data','b.data', 'c.data']
loads = [load(i) for i in inputs]
cleaned = [clean(x) for x in loads]

analysis = analyze(cleaned)
analysis.visualize()
analysis.compute()
```

is there a way to tell Dask to abort a part of the graph and have it execute like this at runtime ?

[image: dask execution graph]

Comment: Have you considered using the async map/submit api of the distributed scheduler? That would allow you to check on the completion/error of a task and decide dynamically if you want to base more work on it.

Comment: No. I will look into that